# Does motion affects the radioactive decay process in a "pre-relativistic" physics?

Tags: special-relativity, time

Does motion affects the decay process in "pre-relativistic" physics? I mean, does motion has independent impact on decay process- i.e. exclude the time dilation effect? My friend argues that maybe time dilation is illusionary and the decay process has been dilated because it has been impacted by its motion.

Comment: https://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Relativity/text/Muons_time_dilation/index.html

Comment: What is moving at relativistic speeds? Why do you think this motion might have any effect on a quantum process?

Comment: It looks like other people may have the same issue with this question as I have. There simply isn’t a pre-relativistic theory which describes muon decay. I am not sure that there is an answer to the question as asked

Comment: @Dale actually, we have to describe it. Tbe muon decay problem is one of the robust proofs that time dilation is true but one of my friends argued that may be muon lived more than their avg. lifetime because motion-independent of the Relativistic process i.e. time dilation- might have an impact on the radioactive process.  Which might question on the time dilation.

Comment: Sure, we do describe it... with relativistic physics. We certainly do not “have to describe it” non-relativistically. If your friend wants a non-relativistic theory then the burden is on him to develop, test, and publish it.